# Vercel Blob instances link in Quickstart page gives 404 error

Tags: http-status-code-404, vercel

I followed the guide [How to Build a Full-Stack Multi-Tenant App Using Next.js](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application).

#### Issue

Vercel Blob instances link in Quickstart page gives 404 error.

Tried refreshing the page and tried 2 different browsers:

- Safari and
- Chrome

What could be the cause and how to solve it?